# Diameter of graph is $\geq 4$

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be any graph such that $\Delta G=k\geq2$. If there are at least $k^3-k^2+k+2$ vertices, show that $\operatorname{diam}(G)\geq 4$.

Can any one give idea on how to approach this problem

Comment: What do you mean by $\Delta G$?

Comment: maximum degree of any vertex in graph

Comment: What if my maximum degree of a graph is 1?

Comment: @Learner In that case the graph is necessarily disconnected. The diameter can be defined as infinite so this still holds.

Answer (score 4):

To show that the diameter of the graph is greater than $4$, let us fix an arbitrary vertex $v$ of $G$. Then we must show the existence of a vertex of $G$ which is *not* reachable from $v$ in $3$ steps or less. Since the maximum degree is $k$, how many vertices (at most) are reachable from any fixed vertex in $3$ steps or less?